# Add Date Range Filter - SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, filter

I am a beginner in SQL and having a problem to get my query to work. All I need to do is to add a date range filter to the query below. I am filtering by the field f.date_value. Parm 2 and Parm 3 will be the date that staff will choose when they run the report. This SQL report run into a built-in SQL tool inside one of our softwares so it is a little different than SQL Developer that we use to access the database. Anyone has any idea on what I need to change on the query below? Thank you very much!

```
SELECT st.dcid,
    st.student_number,
    st.lastfirst,
    st.grade_level,
    to_char(f.date_value,'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    f.fee_type_name,
    f.description,
    f.fee_amount,
    f.fee_paid,
    f.fee_balance
FROM PS.FEE f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENTS ST
        ON f.StudentID = st.ID
WHERE (f.SCHOOLID=%param1%) AND (st.ENROLL_STATUS=0) AND (f.date_value BETWEEN %parm2% AND %parm3%)
ORDER BY st.LASTFIRST
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There really isn't enough information to help you much. I suggest you read these:   [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What software are you using to execute the sql quey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything obvious to offer, except perhaps the use of `to_date` and exactly how you use that depends on the data type and format of the parameters. I assume they are strings, but don't know what format they are supplied (I have used yyyy-mm-dd below).

```
SELECT
    st.dcid
  , st.student_number
  , st.lastfirst
  , st.grade_level
  , to_char(f.date_value, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  , f.fee_type_name
  , f.description
  , f.fee_amount
  , f.fee_paid
  , f.fee_balance
FROM PS.FEE f
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENTS st ON f.StudentID = st.ID
WHERE f.SCHOOLID = %param1%
AND st.ENROLL_STATUS = 0 
AND f.date_value BETWEEN to_date(%parm2%,'yyyy-mm-dd') AND to_date(%parm3%,'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY
    st.LASTFIRST
```

The only other thing to note is that `between` is often a poor way to define a date range - but this in part depends on the time precision of your data. IF your data is accurate to the day only, then `between` as you see above is ok. If there is lower level of precision (e.g. second or lower) then don't use between, instead:

```
AND f.date_value >= to_date(%parm2%,'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND f.date_value < to_date(%parm3%,'yyyy-mm-dd') + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I used the to_date and seems to be working now! I really appreciate your help! Have a great day!